# Issue in REST call

Tags: client-object-model, rest, ajax

I have two methods which will be call on bashed on condition

Code:

```
//Method to add item in TT items list.
function addTTItemsList(url, listname, itemTitle, columnOrder, rowOrder, listName, listItemId, success, failure) {
//Add new item 
    return $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TTItemsListItem' },
            //'Title': itemTitle,
            'xxx': columnOrder,
            'xxx': rowOrder,
            'xxx': listName,
            'xxx': listItemId
        }),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
            //alert("Created");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}   
$('.littcls').each(function () {

    for (var c = 1; c < itemLength; c++) {
        var noOfItemEntry = 0;
        noOfItems++;            
        // This is REST call method
        addTTItemsList(siteurl, listName, 'Title', columnHeading, noOfItems, pageList, totalItems[c], function (data) { 
            noOfItemEntry++;
            allSeletedItems += data.d.ID + ',';

            alert('last id:' + data.d.ID + ' || top :' + allSeletedItems);
        }, function (data) { });
    }
    if ($(this).is(":last-child")) {
        allSeletedItems = allSeletedItems.replace('undefined', '');
        allSeletedItems = allSeletedItems.substring(0, allSeletedItems.length - 1);         
        // this is another REST call
        addTTConfigurationList(siteurl, listConfig, '', txtHeading, txtButton, pageList, buttonItemListId, allSeletedItems, function (data) { }, function (data) { });
    }
});
```

In the code there is 2 methods `addTTItemsList` and `addTTConfigurationList` methods which contain REST calls. The problem I'm facing that my loop is on 'littcls' class. The first method, `addTTItemsList()`, will be called multiple times but second method, `addTTConfigurationList()`, will be called at last and once only. But my second method calls first and after that first method is called.

So, basically issue is of REST call. There is call is running in first method at that time my second method is called. either is should be complete execution of first method then it execute second method.

How to solve this issue.

Comment: Please, add the code from the two methods. If we are to find a solution, we need to see the code from addTTItemsList

Comment: hello SPArchaeologist, I have put code of addTTItemsList

Comment: Do you need to use REST? Can you use JSOM instead?

Answer (score 2):

Return the results of your first call (which will be a jQuery Deferred object) then use that object with jQuery.when() in order to force all of the first calls to complete before the second one can begin:

```
$('.littcls').each(function() {
    // *** use these variables to hold all of the promises you create in the loop
    var addTTItemPromises = [], 
        currRequest;
    for (var c = 1; c < itemLength; c++) {
        var noOfItemEntry = 0;
        noOfItems++;
        // This is REST call method
        currRequest = addTTItemsList(siteurl, listName, 'Title', columnHeading, noOfItems, pageList, totalItems[c], function(data) {
            noOfItemEntry++;
            allSeletedItems += data.d.ID + ',';

            alert('last id:' + data.d.ID + ' || top :' + allSeletedItems);
        }, function(data) {});
        // *** push the request on to the promise array
        addTTItemPromises.push(currRequest);
    }
    if ($(this).is(":last-child")) {
        allSeletedItems = allSeletedItems.replace('undefined', '');
        allSeletedItems = allSeletedItems.substring(0, allSeletedItems.length - 1);
        // this is another REST call
        // *** force the next call to wait on all of the first promises to resolve
        $.when.apply($, addTTItemPromises).then(function() {
            addTTConfigurationList(siteurl, listConfig, '', txtHeading, txtButton, pageList, buttonItemListId, allSeletedItems, function(data) {}, function(data) {});
        })
    }
});
```

That should do what you're looking for, but as wjervis alludes to in the comments to your question -- you may want to consider using the JavaScript Object Model here so you can batch all of these calls, or perform a REST call at the end of this processing that can deliver a payload with all of the items you're creating. Performing many web requests (REST calls in this case) inside of a loop should generally be avoided when possible, in order to minimize the network overhead for each of the requests. Minimizing the number of requests will generally result in a more responsive experience for you and your users.

Comment: Still learning the Deferred object; didn't know about `$.when()` for multiple promises.  Just learned something new.

Comment: normally $.when() expects an arbitrary number of deferreds as arguments, but to use an array of deferreds(and let's be honest, why wouldn't you...) you have to give it this apply syntax which I dislike -- but I dislike it less than extending $.when myself :)